# Play Diablo3 in Separate Speakers than Skype?

Tags: diablo-iii, skype

I want to play skype sounds through my headphones but Diablo 3 sounds through my main speakers? Is this possible / is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are your speakers and headset different devices?

Comment: yes. I have a USB mic and speaker plugged in to my headphone jack. I get 2 options with skype but I cant find any audio options with D3 thought some1 here might know a trick or 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your sound properties, you can set your default communication device to your headset and your speakers as your default sound output. This will allow your skype to come through the headset and game sounds through the speakers.

You may also need to change the sound output in Skype (Tools -> Options -> Audio Settings) to output to your USB headset in the Speaker drop down menu.

Comment: Your my favorite person ever. Works ty, will accept in a minute.

Comment: Not a problem, this goes for a lot of games actually and not just Diablo 3. Starcraft 2 actually has it's own output which is why I'm a little surprised that D3 didn't.